# How to subscribe to webhook notifications for OneNote Business using Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onenote, onenote-api

While the Graph API [supports webhook updates to Business OneDrive "driveItems"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/subscription?view=graph-rest-1.0) and [OneNote notebooks are driveItems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/sp2019/docs/rest-api/resources/package?view=odsp-graph-online), we are only getting notifications from our personal OneDrive account.

We subscribed for webhooks on Business OneDrive account and got the following response --

```
stdClass Object
(
    [@odata.context] => graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#subscriptions/$entity
    [id] => fc4e68d1-9c8f-4fe8-89cd-90fb4b08b38f
    [resource] => me/drive/root
    [applicationId] => 0fb59cce-3499-486e-a05c-4d994644f80a
    [changeType] => updated
    [clientState] => 
    [notificationUrl] => mydomain.com/users/testGraphWebhook
    [expirationDateTime] => 2019-04-12T11:00:00.117Z
    [creatorId] => 12345678 (altered for privacy)
)
```

We have gotten similar successful response subscribing for personal OneDrive account.

For the personal account, we are getting notifications for every change in OneNote pages, but no notifications are coming for OneNote pages stored on Business OneDrive despite the successful subscription.

Is it possible to get notifications for changes made in OneNote pages of Business Account? How can we can change the subscription request or other code to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Anupam,  webhooks is not supported for Office 365 accounts yet. But it is on our backlog. You can up vote this feature at https://onenote.uservoice.com/forums/245490-onenote-developer-apis/suggestions/19496185-webhooks-for-office-365-notes

Comment: Thanks. Because there has not been a status update to any of the now 284 uservoice ideas for the onenote api since 2017,  we assumed all work was being moved to the graph api.  From the 2016 post, we know the onenote api only supported consumer notebooks for webhooks [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/how-to/onenote-sync), but for Microsoft Graph API Business OneDrive is supported as of 2019 [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/webhooks?view=graph-rest-1.0).  The documentation is a bit confusing.